# Does CTRL+C works in the whole world

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to know if CTRL+C (copy) keyboard shortcut works on all Windows versions above '98, all Non-English Windows and on all keyboards (English, German, Chinese...)?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: No - (external) software may alter anything - does a Chines keyboard have a C (and how many ctrl keys it might have)?

Comment: @DieterLücking just for your curiosity, a Chinese keyboard generally looks like an American keyboard, and they do have all the letters of the alphabet. Chinese use specific software to type Chinese characters through pinyin or other input methods by pressing alphanumeric keys. [Here's a little explanation](http://www.slate.com/articles/news_and_politics/explainer/2006/02/what_does_a_chinese_keyboard_look_like.html).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a conceptual programming problem within the scope defined in the help center.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if nothing else to avoid confusing users. However the original mappings were

```
 Shift+Delete = Cut
 Ctrl+Insert = Copy
 Shift+Insert = Paste
```

This should still work and are language independent.

Comment: Thank you very much. Does this mean that (in programming) when simulating keypress I should use CTRL+Insert before CTRL+C?

Comment: That would be preferable. I heard anecdotes of other languages having different mappings using the letters but those three should be independent

Comment: PS. I think it's Shift+Delete for cut... Please edit answer :)

Comment: Anecdotally, there are times when programs won't respond to one or other methods of cutting and pasting, so I'll try both. Then there's the linux-land middle click to paste. At times in Linux, it is like there are three different clipboards.